# Extract VAT identification number with Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract the German VAT number (Umsatzsteuer-Identifikationsnummer) from a text.

```
string = "I want to get this DE813992525 number."
```

I know, that the correct regex for this problem is `(?xi)^( (DE)?[0-9]{9}|)$`.
It works great according to my [demo](https://regex101.com/r/5BVPKP/1).

What I tried is:

```
string = "I want to get this DE813992525 number.
match = re.compile(r'(?xi)^( (DE)?[0-9]{9}|)$')
print(match.findall(string))

>>>>>> []
```

What I would like to get is:

```
print(match.findall(string))
>>>>>  DE813992525
```

Comment: Why not just `^DE[0-9]{9}$`https://regex101.com/r/FDuzNE/1 See https://ideone.com/nRaAXx

Comment: no, it's [not correct one](https://regex101.com/r/yMFxD7/1) - e.g. `$` anchor means end of string and your test string VAT number is not at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When searching within a string, dont use `^` and `$`:

```
import re
string = """I want to get this DE813992525 number.
I want to get this DE813992526 number.
"""
match = re.compile(r'DE[0-9]{9}')
print(match.findall(string))
```

Out:

```
['DE813992525', 'DE813992526']
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
What would be the regex if the numbers are seperated: ``DE 813 992 525`` and ``DE 813992526``

Comment: Or could use the `OR` operator in the regexp: `DE[0-9 ]{12}|DE[0-9]{9}`